# How to validate enable disable values of the dropDown using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have percentage value in the drop-down which can be changed, some values are disabled and some are enabled?
I need to verify the value and check whether it is enabled or disabled?

is there any way to get XPath of one value and check its enabled or disabled?

Find the image to get more details

[image]

Comment: Check in firepath once whether this xpath //select[@id=level_points] selects all option. If yes, then try selecting option from there as per your requirement like //select[@id=level_points]//option[@value='100'] and then check if it is enabled or disabled like driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath here")).isEnabled() If the xpath  //select[@id=level_points] does not work then verify once whether select option are inside iframe. If yes, switch to iframe and then follow above instruction.

Comment: Thank you this help me to catch the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use the below code to check whether the options are enabled or disabled. try using the below code.

```
WebElement selectDropDown=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@id='level_points']"));
List<WebElement> options=selectDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++)
{
 try{
    String isDisabled=options.get(i).getAttribute("disabled");
     //Write the required code if disabled
    }
 catch(Exception ex)
   {
    //Write required code if not disabled
   } 
}
```

I don't have Eclipse in this machine, so please take of syntactical errors if any.
you will get all the disabled options in try block, because you have that attribute, and in catch block you will get the options which are not disabled.